# Adding multiple conditional tags in a function?

Tags: php, functions

I have about 30 categories that need to be included within this function list:

```
add_filter( 'generate_blog_columns','tu_portfolio_columns' );
function tu_portfolio_columns( $columns ) {
    if ( is_category( '16' ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

I tried this:

```
if ( is_category( '16','12','45' ) ) {
        return true;
    }
```

What can I do to tweak this function to add more categories?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to put those category IDs into an array really, the IF can only handle one condition at a time, so you could change your if statement to be:

```
if( is_category('16') || is_category('12') ) {
```

In PHP, the **||** stands for **OR**, whilst **&&** stands for **AND**, so your if statement is saying if category 16, **OR** category 12 in the above.

However, it makes more sense to do an array and loop through it, so you end up with something like this:

```
add_filter( 'generate_blog_columns','tu_portfolio_columns' );
function tu_portfolio_columns( $columns ) {
    $cats = array('16', '12', '45');

    foreach($cats as $cid) {
        if ( is_category( $cid ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return $columns;
}
```

It is untested, but I think it should do the trick for you... In line 3 we are creating the array of category IDs that you want, and then on line 5 we are putting that array into a foreach loop so each ID can be called once at a time. Then within that is your IF statement as it was which retrieves the current loop iterations category ID and checks it using WP's `is_category` function.

Comment: is_category() accepts an array. None of this is necessary.

Comment: Interesting. Does it accept an array in an if statement natively??

Comment: Yes: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to give an example so as the answer to this question can be correctly updated and we can learn something. Henry has checked this as working, so I presume it's good, but if it's a bit on the verbose side, then I'd be interested to know how you'd do it. I presume it would simply be `if( is_category( array(1, 2, 3))) :`, but why not just submit an answer?